# What should I read to learn about the different models of computation used in algorithm and especially data structure analysis?

Tags: ds.data-structures, amortized-analysis

Are there any good surveys? Courses? Lecture notes?

I'm especially interested in material with practice exercises, if any is available.

Thanks!

Comment: [Beyond worst case analysis](http://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/bwca/bwca.html).